l2-norm of matrix products
I have a matrix $Q\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}(m>n)$, where the columns of Q are unit and mutually orthogonal. $W\in \mathbb{R}^{m\times m}$ is a diagonal matrix with diagonal elements 0 or 1, and $WQ$ has full column rank (which means that there must be at least n diagonal elements equal to 1 in W). Now I'm trying to prove that the largest eigenvalue of $Q^TWQ$ is 1. I already know that $\Vert Q^TWQ\Vert_2\leq 1$, and if $\Vert Q^TWQ\Vert_2 < 1$, then for any $x\neq 0 \in \Bbb{R}^{n}$, $\Vert Q^TWQx\Vert_2\leq \Vert Q^TWQ \Vert_2 \Vert x\Vert_2 < \Vert x\Vert_2$. So, if there exists a vector $x\neq 0$, such that $\Vert Q^TWQx\Vert_2 = \Vert x\Vert_2$, it would imply that $\Vert Q^TWQ\Vert_2 = 1$. However, I have failed to find such a vector. Can anyone help? Or is this approach(conclusion) incorrect? Thanks a lot!

@TheoBendit You are right. $W$ is in $\mathbb{R}^{m\times m}$. Thank you very much!

The conclusion is not correct. Take, for example:
$$\pmatrix{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}&\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}\pmatrix{1&0\\0&0}\pmatrix{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}=\pmatrix{\frac{1}{2}},$$
which clearly has only the eigenvalue $\frac{1}{2}$.

This example is nice! Can Q be extended to multi-columns?

@kaideng Certainly:$$\pmatrix{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}&\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}&0&0\0&0&\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}&\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}\pmatrix{1&0&0&0\0&0&0&0\0&0&1&0\0&0&0&0}\pmatrix{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}&0\\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}&0\0&\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\0&\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}=\pmatrix{\frac{1}{2}&0\0&\frac{1}{2}}.$$Three columns is also available on request. :)

I get it, thank you so much!
